# jpanel is shifted over when trying to repaint

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to use Swing components to manipulate the elements i am painting, with swing stuff in a jpanel on the right of the screen, and my painting stuff in a jpanel on the left of the screen. I have a JButton named btn1 which when pressed, repaints my jpanel with a black rectangle moved over ten pixels. However when i repaint the gui, the entire gui seems to be shifted about 5 px down and 5 px to the right when the black rect moves 10 px to the right. Then eventually, the black rect stops appearing after moving half way across the jpanel. Is there something i am doing wrong with using painting and swing stufff? i went through the custom painting documentation as well as this article [article tut here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/GraphicsExercises.html) but when i tried to implement these concepts myself, i still had weird problems like this.

Thanks for your help! i am new to this so any clarification / links to other resources would help me a lot. :)

Main.java

```
package p3p4;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    
    private GamePanel gPnl;
    
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    
    public Main() {
        gPnl = new GamePanel();
        
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        JPanel rightPnl = new JPanel();
        rightPnl.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        contentPane.add(rightPnl, BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("THIS IS A BUTTON");
        rightPnl.add(btn1);
        
        btn1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                gPnl.setX(gPnl.getX() + 10);
                gPnl.repaint();
            }
        });
        
//      JPanel centerPnl = new JPanel();
//      centerPnl.setBackground(Color.gray);
//      contentPane.add(centerPnl);
        
        contentPane.add(gPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
    }

}
```

GamePanel.java

```
package p3p4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
    private int x = 0, y = 0;
    
    public GamePanel() {
        setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(x,  y,  50,  50);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why you dont want to extend components. JPanel also has a 'getX', You might want to check if your layout is calling 'getX' and getting the 'x' you're using, and not the position of the component instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the methods `getX` and `getY` are used by swing to manage layout. So you're essentially confusing swing.

You could just change the names of those methods, maybe `getRectangleX` or something along those lines.

I prefer to use composition over inheritance these days. *Although, you might actually want to extend JPanel for layout purposes etc.*

```
public class GamePanel{
    private int x = 0, y = 0;
    JPanel panel;
    public GamePanel() {
        panel =  new JPanel(){
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.fillRect(x,  y,  50,  50);
            }
        };
        panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
    
    

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public JPanel getJPanel(){
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Then when you add it, `contentPane.add(gPnl.getJPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);`

In a similar manner, I would stop extending JFrame, and just create a JFrame instance.

Comment: that worked, thanks! i literally spent the last 10 hours trying to learn more about painting to figure this problem out.